# Unmatching Regex - Validators return OK

Tags: regular-expression

Confused as to why this:

`sudo ps aux | grep -E '\/erts-[1-9]\d*(\.\d+)+\/bin\/beam'`

Does not return a match for the `beam.smp` process of the form:

`/opt/api_presence/erts-8.3/bin/beam.smp`

All regex testers/validators confirm this returns the expected output given what was put in. At the very least you can test with `/bin/beam`.

In the comments, user muru has identified my issue.

Comment: Your regex testers aren't testing for grep, so they're useless. `\d` needs GNU grep with `-P`. The `/` doesn't need to escaped.

Comment: Terrific - thanks for the clarity, muru.

Comment: Comment via user muru has corrected my issue.

Comment: The right thing to do here is to either write the entire solution in the Answer box, or to accept the proposed duplicate as having solved your problem. Using the Answer box to say "a comment solved it" is Not An Answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-P` flag was needed.

`sudo ps aux | grep -P '\/erts-[1-9]\d*(\.\d+)+\/bin\/beam'` has returned the proper result